# CSS specifity / inheritance issue

Tags: css, inheritance

I'm attaching a 3rd party component to a div element (container). This div element is inside a from and the form has the class `cssform`. my main css sheet I use contains the definition:

```
.cssform div {
    max-width: 680px;
    clear: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 8px 0;
    padding-left: 155px;
}
```

My container is now affected by this css which makes the 3rd party component visual unusable.

How can I "overwrite" or "reset" this above css so that it is not applied in any children of my container especially taking into account 3rd party component itself creates div elements below mine also affected from this forms css

EDIT:

The structure is

```
<form class="cssform">
  <section>
    <div>
      <label></label><input>            
    </div>
    <div id="container"></div>         
    <div>
      <label></label><input>            
    </div>  
  <section>
</form>
```

I fixed this by simply giving all the divs except the container an addtional css class and using that to assign the forms style. that way my container is not affected. I'm not adding this as an answer because it's technical not an answer to my question but a work-around.

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Is the div you're targeting the 3rd party component or not?

Comment: The one I add is the container to which the 3rd party component is added. But the 3rd party component itself is full of nested divs, all which are affected by this css. Ideally I would like to reset all styles for my container div and all children.

Answer (score 0):

If you your div element is, lets say, the third child of its parent container, you can use the pseudo-class `:not` with `:nth-child(3)`:

```
.cssform div:not(:nth-child(3)) {
    max-width: 680px;
    clear: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 8px 0;
    padding-left: 155px;
}
```

You may have to edit the selector depending on your entire block of code. But I believe the CSS selector you are looking for is **`:not(:nth-child(n))`**.

Comment: This doesn't work probably because the nesting in 3rd party component is deep, eg. it also has to apply for 4,5,6 etc nth children.

Comment: If you try adding `> *` (it would select all child elements recursively) to your CSS rule?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to style only one particular div, the solution depends on which exact HTML structure you have. For example, if the form looks like

```html
<form class="cssform">
  <section>
    <div>
      <div> this one!
        <div> but not this one! </div>
      </div>
      <div> nor this one! </div>
    <div>
  <section>
</form>
```

then the css needs to be like this:

```css
.cssform > section > div > div:first-child {...}
```

Hope this helps.